# JQuery select all decendant li in ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have an hierarchical UL / LI list, is it possible to fetch all decendant LI's from the root UL using JQuery?

Currently I do recursion from within UL.children('li').each(...)

```
(function foo($ul) {
    $ul.children("li").each(function () {
        var $li = $(this);
        tabMap[$li.find('a').attr('href')] = $li;
        $li.children("ul").each(function () {
            foo($(this));
        });
    });
})($ul);
```

Which works fine, but I it would be nice if it was possible to do this in one go so to say.

Also, would it be possible to do the same but for parents?
e.g. find all parent,grandparent,grandgrand* of type LI from another LI ?

Comment: `UL.find("li").each(...` Or if you want `a` elements ultimately, `UL.find("li a").each(...`. Probably worth spending some time in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: If you find yourself using recursive methods with your jQuery selectors, you're probably doing it wrong (i.e less efficiently/easily than you could be) `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the descendent `UL` elements with [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$ul.find("li")
```

You can get all the ancestors with [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$li.parents("li");
```

You can find all the jQuery tree traversal methods [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 1):

To collect all href's of anchor links which are direct children of list-items within some root list, start from the root, find all such links, then put them in the map and associate them with their parent.

```
var tabMap = {};
$("ul#root").find("li > a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    var $li = $(this).parent("li");
    tabMap[link] = $li;
});
```

Note that the filter parameter in the call to `parent` isn't necessary, but it helps make it clear what you're expecting to find there. Additionally `ul#root` is overly-specific since the ID is unique; I only added the ul here to make it obvious that this is your top-level list, and you should put the correct for that element based on your HTML.

Comment: Is there any difference performancewise in selecting eg. li.children('a') vs a.parent('li') or is it same same?

Comment: Either way you're traversing one level of the DOM, so if it's one to one it's the same overhead. However if the `li` has many children, using the `children` method requires checking each of the children against the selector, which can be a lot; the `parent` method is always fast because an element can only ever have a single parent. Since you traverse the tree to find the link in the first place, however, the amortized costs for both operations are likely to be the same.